# How to access a string in a void method from another void method?

Tags: java, android

```
        public void WeatherInfo(){
    .......
    String weatherLocation = weatherLoc[1].toString();
........
}
```

basically I have this dynamic string that is in a void called WeatherInfo.

But I need to get the weatherLocation string from another void, like this

```
    public void WeatherChecker(){

    YahooWeatherUtils yahooWeatherUtils = YahooWeatherUtils.getInstance();
  yahooWeatherUtils.queryYahooWeather(getApplicationContext(), weatherLocation, this);
}
```

Therefore I need to be able to access weatherLocation from this void.

How do I do this?

Comment: Call them methods, not voids.  Void is just the return type of the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass it as a parameter or create a "global variable"

IE you could do either of the following...

```
public void methodOne(String string){
    System.out.println(string);
}
public void methodTwo(){
    String string = "This string will be printed by methodOne";
    methodOne(string);
}
```

OR (a better solution)

Create a global variable under the class declaration...

```
public class ThisIsAClass {

String string; //accessible globally
....
//way down the class

    public void methodOne(){
        System.out.println(string);
    }
    public void methodTwo(){
        String string = "This string will be printed by methodOne"; //edit the string here
        methodOne();
    }
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Of course you will have to change `String string;` accordingly but it is the same concept with any variable.

You said that your "sentence" is created in one of these methods and it hasn't been created when you declare it globally. All you need to do is create it globally, `String weatherLocation = null;` and then set it whenever you need to. I think it your example it would be under `weatherInfo()`

```
public void WeatherInfo(){
    weatherLocation = weatherLoc[1].toString();
}
```

Instead of creating a new one we just edit the one we created globally.

-Henry

Answer (score 4):

This is a question of [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29). You have declared a local variable, so it can only be accessed **locally**. If you wish to access the variable outside of the method, either pass a reference or declare it **globally**.

```
public void method1()
{
   String str = "Hello";
   // str is only accessible inside method1 
}


String str2 = "hello there"; 
// str2 is accessible anywhere in the class.
```

**Edit**

As pointed out, you should look at the [Java naming Conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm).

Comment: give an example and +1 and a link to follow java code conventions

Comment: The problem is that the weather location is taken from a whole sentence whenever the user talks and presses a certain button after talking. Like, if the sentence is "what is the weather like in NYC" the button's method clears out unnecessary words and sets weatherLocation as NYC. If I declare weatherLocation outside of the button's onclick method it will not work since there will be no sentence to work with in the first place.

Comment: Be careful. There's a difference between *declare* and *define*. You can *declare* the variable outside of the method, but you can't use it until it has been *defined* within the method. You could just include a check in the second method, with something like: `if(weatherLocation == null) return;`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do any of the following

1) pass the string as parameter and set the value

or

2) use a member variable and use a getter to get the variable

Comment: and 3) follow java code conventions :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish, or what functions are calling what other functions... but you could just pass `weatherLocation` in as as a parameter. Is this what you are looking for?

```
public void WeatherChecker(String weatherLocation){
  YahooWeatherUtils yahooWeatherUtils = YahooWeatherUtils.getInstance();
  yahooWeatherUtils.queryYahooWeather(getApplicationContext(), weatherLocation, this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly as local variables in a method only exist from their declaration to the end of the block (which is the end of the method at latest).

If you need to access a variable in more than one method you can make it a class variable (or field). Once you assign a value to a field it is saved as state of the object and can be accessed and modified at any time later. This of course means you have to set it first.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try declaring your String higher up in the scope of the method your attempting to use it. You would have to make sure WeatherInfo() was called first (maybe in a constructor) so that it gets initialized or you would get odd results.

```
public Class {
String weatherLocation = null;

public void WeatherInfo(){
    ........
    weatherLocation = weatherLoc[1].toString();
    ........
}
public void WeatherChecker(){
    YahooWeatherUtils yahooWeatherUtils = YahooWeatherUtils.getInstance();
    yahooWeatherUtils.queryYahooWeather(getApplicationContext(), weatherLocation, this);    
}
}
```